# PrintTicket scopes (default, user, job, document, page etc)

Tags: c#, .net, printing, xps

I'm completing the construction of a webservice that builds and prints out XPS documents sending them to various print queues on various print servers. The webservice runs in 2 modes depending on site deployment. The first is using the app pool identity account as the print user, the second mode uses user impersonation for "follow me" type printers, so that the user is registered against the print job. This all works fine.

I have to target particular trays on the printqueues and set various other parameters for each job, so I've generated printickets adding the tray namespace to the xml and this also appears to work.

My concern is this (and is where I need some hand holding), because I'm doing all this STA threaded server side, say Bob running as Bob prints 200 documents of a mix (A4, A5, envelope) and the tickets switch off say duplexing on the printer and my app pool identity account is running say 20 printing threads with multiple documents of various target trays with various parameters at once, am I going to get any issues or am I going to knacker the default printer queue settings?

According to MS, MergeAndValidatePrintTicket can be scoped at various levels (I'll settle for job level)  but I just wonder if anyone with experience of this scenario can validate this as true and if there any gotchas out there, because this whole .Net printing malarkey seems to be riddled with them.

'lil tip for anyone doing this. If your target printers are simple with say only 3 trays of different sizes, just set the media size (ISOA4 or whatever) in the ticket and set the input bin to unknown and the printer will work it out. Unfortunately, the printers I'm targeting have about 7 bins, so I have to target the exact tray.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It depends on what you do with the tickets. If you attach the ticket to the job, you're fine. If you are setting the ticket on the queue, you're not. Do you have any example code where you use the tickets?

Comment: Hi Jon...I'll be scoping at the job level, so thanks for the reassurance. I'm recoding tomorrow. I've got an admin site that scans each print server's print queue and pulls off the bin names for that printer. As I do that I want to create the print tickets and store all that info in a database. I have a mapping table (that is manual) specifying the media size, printer type and bin namespace which I'll join in a view with the printer data and join that to the document table so doc A4 -> A4 Lex ns0000:Tray 2 -> Lex ns0000:Tray 2 print ticket. I'll be using .net 4.5 addjob with ticket overload.

Comment: ran out of space...I'll be using queue.userPrintTicket then validationResult.mergeAndValidatePrintTicket then hopefully using this .Net 4.5 queue.addjob overload that has a printticket variable. I'll try and pop some code up tomorrow night (Mon)

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to show solution**

Jon...this is the relevant section...

PrintTicket ptclone = pqTarget.UserPrintTicket****.Clone();**** <--remove Clone()

//my method below for specifying the tray to use for the job and other settings. poj is my printJob class

PrintTicket pt = GetPrintTicketForJob(ptclone, poj.trayMediaSize, poj.trayNameSpace, poj.trayUri);

ValidationResult vr= pqTarget.MergeAndValidatePrintTicket(ptclone, pt, PrintTicketScope.JobScope);

**pqTarget.UserPrintTicket = vr.ValidatedPrintTicket;** <--remove this

//pqTarget.Commit() // the print server in localPrintServer mode didn't like that under user impersonation

**PrintSystemJobInfo pj = pqTarget.AddJob(poj.id, poj.fileName, false)** <--don't do this

I tried using the .Net 4.5 overload that has the print ticket in it, but the server in localPrintServer mode didn't understand the method even though the server has .Net 4.5 on it and which was...

**PrintSystemJobInfo pj = pqTarget.AddJob(poj.id.ToString(), poj.fileName, false, vr.ValidatedPrintTicket)** <--do this instead .Net 4.5 and it all works

Everything works fine with the following exceptions....

1) on the mfds which are controlled by 3rd party software and use user impersonation, the default duplex setting stays active for the first document printed, after that, it's fine. It works OK for the Lexmarks (app pool idenity used). Trays are properly assigned on both types as are the other settings.

2) Dates and numbers (which are inserted as strings into the documents) and appear OK in the XPS viewer get reformatted as san serif even if the paragraph they are in is in say Times New Roman which is baffling.

Can you spot any screw ups?

regards

Neil

Comment: pqTarget.UserPrintTicket = vr.ValidatedPrintTicket; is trying to change the ticket on the queue. This is definitely not what you want to do. Did you verify that your project is targeting the .net 4.5 framework? Just having it installed is not sufficient.

Comment: Also, you should edit your updates into the original question, rather than add them as an answer.

Comment: Project is targeting 4.5, I checked and if it wasn't you don't see the overloads. There wasn't enough space in comments, but apologies for bad form. I'm confused (lost) as to where I apply vr.ValidatedPrintTicket then? I'll try again this morning. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: BTW, the date and number problem appears to be a bug in the dll I'm using for conversion and the manufacturer of that is provding me with a fix, so one less problem to solve. I spent a lot of time today trying different methods of getting ticket attached to the job, but none seemed to work. The original user print ticket is always left intact though and retains it's settings, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I was being dumb. Remove Clone() from the first line, don't point the validated ticket at the user print ticket and it works